# Nested for loop always showing the last data

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, closures

Hi have a javascript code:

```js
var outerSet = [{date: '2016-12-12:00', value: 50}, {date: '2016-12-13:00', value: 50},
                {date: '2016-12-14:00', value: 70}, {date: '2016-12-15:00', value: 50}];
    
var hourlyData = ['2016-12-13:01','2016-12-13:02','2016-12-13:03',
                  '2016-12-13:04','2016-12-13:05']

var iterator = 0;
var tempData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < outerSet.length; i++) {

  var innerItem = outerSet[i];

  if (innerItem.date === '2016-12-13:00') {

    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      tempData[iterator] = innerItem;
      tempData[iterator].date = hourlyData[j];
      iterator++;
    }
  }
}
console.log('temp data', tempData);
```

I want to have then new tempData array's date value to have values like

```
[{date: '2016-12-12:01', value: 50},
 {date: '2016-12-13:02', value: 50},
 {date: '2016-12-14:03', value: 70},
 {date: '2016-12-15:04', value: 50}];
```

but instead it always gives me back

```
[{date: '2016-12-12:04', value: 50},
 {date: '2016-12-13:04', value: 50},
 {date: '2016-12-14:04', value: 70},
 {date: '2016-12-15:04', value: 50}];
```

This could be a closure problem, but I am unable to figure out the issue.

Here is the fiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/nck66sre/

Comment: *"This could be a closure problem"* - It couldn't be: there are no functions defined in your code. No closures. (No functions called either, except for `console.log()` at the end.)

Comment: Your questions is a bit confusing, because the piece of code you provided outputs 
`[{ date: "2016-12-13:04", value: 50 }, 
{ date: "2016-12-13:04", value: 50 }, { date: "2016-12-13:04", value: 50 }, { date: "2016-12-13:04", value: 50 }]` and not what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
tempData[iterator] = innerItem;
```

On each iteration, you assign the current `tempData` array element equal to *the same* object. So when the loop ends, all four elements in the array reference the same object. (So in fact your code doesn't output what you say it does.)

You need to create a new object on each iteration:

```
tempData[iterator] = { date: hourlyData[j], value: innerItem.value };
```

In context:

```js
var outerSet = [{date: '2016-12-12:00', value: 50}, {date: '2016-12-13:00', value: 50},
                {date: '2016-12-14:00', value: 70}, {date: '2016-12-15:00', value: 50}];
    
var hourlyData = ['2016-12-13:01','2016-12-13:02','2016-12-13:03',
                  '2016-12-13:04','2016-12-13:05']

var tempData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < outerSet.length; i++) {

  var innerItem = outerSet[i];

  if (innerItem.date === '2016-12-13:00') {

    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      tempData.push({ date: hourlyData[j], value: innerItem.value });
    }
  }
}
console.log('temp data', tempData);
```

(Note: I've used `.push()` and done away with the `iterator` variable, but that's just by way of tidying up, it's not related to your problem.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change if condition based on what you want to get. Please refere this code.

```
     var outerSet = [{date: '2016-12-12:00', value: 50}, {date: '2016-12-13:00', value: 50},{date: '2016-12-14:00', value: 70},{date: '2016-12-15:00', value: 50}];

     var hourlyData = ['2016-12-13:01','2016-12-13:02','2016-12-13:03','2016-12-13:04','2016-12-13:05']

      var iterator = 0;

      var tempData = [];

      for (var i=0; i<outerSet.length; i++) {

        var innerItem =  outerSet[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
             if (innerItem.date === '2016-12-13:00') {
                tempData[iterator] = innerItem;
                tempData[iterator].date = hourlyData[j];
                iterator++;
            }
        }
      }
      console.log('temp data', tempData);
```

Comment: I cant do that. In my case, I want to iterate 4 times if I satisfy that 'if' condition. Then, use the 'hourlyData' array and populate the tempData with the indices

Answer (score 0):

```
var outerSet = [{date: '2016-12-12:00', value: 50}, {date: '2016-12-13:00', value: 50},{date: '2016-12-14:00', value: 70},{date: '2016-12-15:00', value: 50}];

var hourlyData = ['2016-12-13:01','2016-12-13:02','2016-12-13:03','2016-12-13:04','2016-12-13:05']

      var iterator = 0;

      var tempData = [];

      for (var i=0; i<outerSet.length; i++) {

        var innerItem =  outerSet[i];

        if (innerItem.date === '2016-12-13:00') {

          for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
             //remember object get value by refference and you need create new object then add value for object property
              tempData[iterator] = {};

              tempData[iterator].value = innerItem.value;

              tempData[iterator].date = hourlyData[j];
              iterator++;
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(tempData));
```

Answer (score 0):

类似传递指针

**English translation:** all pointers point to the same object

```
function createNew(date,value){
    var obj ={
        "date":date,
        "value":value
    };
    return obj;
}

var outerSet = [{date: '2016-12-12:00', value: 40}, {date: '2016-12-13:00', value: 50},{date: '2016-12-14:00', value: 70},{date: '2016-12-15:00', value: 60}];
var hourlyData = ['2016-12-13:10','2016-12-13:20','2016-12-13:30','2016-12-13:40','2016-12-13:50'];

var tempData = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<outerSet.length; i++) {
    var innerItem =  outerSet[i];
    if (innerItem.date == '2016-12-13:00') {
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            var tempOuter=createNew(hourlyData[j],innerItem.value);
            tempData.push(tempOuter);
        }
    }
}
console.log('temp data', tempData);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in English.

Comment: I‘m sorry,my English is poor.I thought that it's like pointers,all pointers point to the same object.